# SQLITE3 Объединение таблиц в базах данных SQLite: JOIN и SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Требуется объединить 2 таблицы.
Пробую сделать это через `LEFT JOIN`.
Получилось следующее.

Имеется данный SQL запрос:

```
SELECT vk_app_sender_app.id, 
    vk_app_sender_app.uid, 
    vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share, 
    vk_app_sender_app.title, 
    vk_app_sender_app.id_app, 
   (vk_app_sender_share_app.id) as share_app_id, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app
   ) as count,
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app 
    AND vk_app_all_visits.first_visit BETWEEN strftime('%s',(julianday('now') - (1))) AND strftime('%s',(julianday('now') + (1)))
   ) as cnt_new 
FROM vk_app_sender_app 
    LEFT JOIN vk_app_sender_share_app ON vk_app_sender_app.id_app = vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app;
```

Результат №1 на картинке.

Требуемый результат:

Нужно получить результат в котором `vk_app_sender_app.uid = 26887374` и `vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share = 26887374`

Пробую так:

```
SELECT vk_app_sender_app.id, 
    vk_app_sender_app.uid, 
    vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share, 
    vk_app_sender_app.title, 
    vk_app_sender_app.id_app, 
   (vk_app_sender_share_app.id) as share_app_id, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app
   ) as count, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app 
    AND vk_app_all_visits.first_visit BETWEEN strftime('%s',(julianday('now') - (1))) AND strftime('%s',(julianday('now') + (1)))
   ) as cnt_new 
FROM vk_app_sender_app 
    LEFT JOIN vk_app_sender_share_app ON vk_app_sender_app.id_app = vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app 
WHERE vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share = 26887374 
    AND vk_app_sender_share_app.uid = vk_app_sender_app.uid;
```

Результат №2 на картинке.

Как сделать так чтобы был результат №3 как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UDP:** создал проект на `sqlfiddle.com` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7252b/1

Comment: вам самим то удобно читать свой запрос, написанный в одну строку?

Comment: нет конечно, будем совершенствоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы соединяете таблицы через `left join` (типа `a left join b`), а потом в `where` накладываете условия на строки из таблицы `b`, то ваш `left join` автоматически превращается в `inner join`.

Не до конца понял, что вам нужно, но попробуйте так:

```
SELECT vk_app_sender_app.id, 
    vk_app_sender_app.uid, 
    vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share, 
    vk_app_sender_app.title, 
    vk_app_sender_app.id_app, 
   (vk_app_sender_share_app.id) as share_app_id, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app
   ) as count, 
   (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vk_app_all_visits 
    WHERE vk_app_all_visits.id_app=vk_app_sender_app.id_app 
    AND vk_app_all_visits.first_visit BETWEEN strftime('%s',(julianday('now') - (1))) AND strftime('%s',(julianday('now') + (1)))
   ) as cnt_new 
FROM vk_app_sender_app 
    LEFT JOIN vk_app_sender_share_app ON vk_app_sender_app.id_app = vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app 
        AND vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share = 26887374 
WHERE 1=1
    AND (vk_app_sender_app.uid = '26887374' or vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share = 26887374);
```

Comment: По вашему запросу получаю следующее: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9De3F.jpg ,

нужно получить из таблицы vk_app_sender_app все поля с uid = 26887374 , 
также из таблицы vk_app_sender_share_app получить поле с uid_share = 26887374. 

В результате получиться должно следующее: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbfxj.jpg

Comment: @KyKyIIIKuH подправил запрос, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7252b/4/0) выдает также, как и у вас на скрине.

Comment: то что нужно,большое спасибо!